# Pest-proof and air-seal electrical wire penetrations in stud walls

Tags: electrical, wiring, insulation, pest-control

I'm replacing all the wiring in my house, and I've decided that I would like to make it as difficult as possible for any bugs or rodents to travel inside my wall cavities through the holes that electrical wiring and pipes run through.  Is there a "best" way to seal up the holes that the NM cable runs through?

I considered the 3M red foam, but I'm not sure if that's effective against bugs and rodents.  Should I pack the holes with rockwool, then cover that with fire block caulk?

Answer (score 3):

Plug the holes with fire caulk (IMHO rockwool serves no useful purpose in your proposed scheme.)

If you really want to do a better job, particularly with respect to rodents, ditch the NM and use MC or AC cable instead, or run EMT conduit. But for sealing the penetrations, that's what fire caulk is made to do.

Comment: Thanks.  I just mentioned the rockwool as packing if the hole size was too large for the fire caulk.  I wasn't sure what size gap I could fill with that.  I haven't even ripped down the drywall, so I don't know what I'm going to find in there when I do.  The house was built in 1978, so...